# get Object in List<Object> using the equals method?

Tags: java

how to get a specific `java` object from `java.util.List<Object>` using `equals` method
exemple :

```
  Class Person{
       String name;
       int age;
       //...

       @Override
       public boolean equals(String str) {
            return (this.name.equals(str.name));
       }
    }

main{
   List<Person> list = personDao.findAll();

   if(list.contain("joe")){
      // how to get the Person named joe ????
   }
}
```

Comment: The signature of your `equals()` method is wrong.

Comment: More importantly, that's not what `Object.equals` is for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a reference to the specific Person in the List:

```
Person foo = null;
for (Person p : list) {
    if (p.getName().equals("joe")) {
        foo = p;
        break;
    }
}
// now foo is your person (if he exists) or null (if he doesnt exist);
```

This will only find the first Person named joe.

Comment: without creating a new instance of Person

Comment: There is no way to do this with `contains`, without creating a new instance of `Person`, and with a correct implementation of `Object.equals`.

Answer (score 3):

The signature of your Person.equals() method is incorrect... argument type should always be "Object", like this:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (obj instanceof Person) && ((Person) obj).name.equals(this.name);
}
```

Then jlordoless's suggestion of using list.contains(new Person("name") will work.

Answer (score 2):

Simply iterate. There's no method on the `List` interface that returns an object from the list.

```
Person joe = null;
List<Person> persons = personDao.findAll();
for (Person thisPerson : persons) {
  if ("joe".equals(thisPerson.getName())) {
     joe = thisPerson;
     break;
  }
}
```

This will set `Person joe` to the *first* person named joe. If you're looking for the *last* one in the collection, remove the `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have a design flaw here. What happens if there are 2 joe-s?

If you don't have duplicate names you can create a getter for the name in `Person`:

```
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
```

and after that you can do this:

```
Person joe = null;
for(Person person : list) {
    if("joe".equals(person.getName()) {
        joe = person;
        break;
    }
}
```

This way you avoid creating unnecessary instances of `Person`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use equals like that. Overriding `equals` is somewhat complex, you have to verride `hashcode` too, for example. A list-based solution with minimal changes:

```
Class Person{
   String name;
   int age;
   //...

   public String getName() {
        return name;
   }
}

main {
   List<Person> list = personDao.findAll();

   Person foundPerson = null;
   for(Person person : list) {
       if (person.getName().equals("joe")) {
           foundPerson = person;
           break;
       }
   }

   if (foundPerson != null) {
       // do something
   }
}
```

However, I would consider using a `Map<String, Person>`, with name as key. Overriding `equals` in Person while ignoring age does not sound very good, really.

Answer (score 0):

@Hyde: Can not answer on your answer. Overriding "hashCode" is required if and only if Hashing is used. If person wants to use HashMap or Hashing related other APIs than only he must override hashCode and equals... Otherwise "equals" works fine.

Comment: I disagree. If you are overriding `equals` in order to be able to use some containers, you are very likely to accidentally stick it into a container which uses `hashcode`. It doesn't take many keystrokes to change container type in Java, and you should be using interface types instead of actual container class names anyway, so you shouldn't even care which container class it is! You can always make a custom method, if you want quick&dirty. And even if it is toy code, do no write bad code, because bad habits stick, and also toy code has tendency to become non-toy code.

Comment: My point was, Overriding hashCode with equals is not mandatory though good practice to follow.